# Response Time in Robot Framework

Tags: appium, robotframework

Is there any way to know the time taken for each action to finish in Robot Framework???

Like For example, I want to rotate screen 90  degrees 10 times, how to time it or how to average the time taken by these actions??

Comment: How do you start your test scripts? Console or some IDE (f.e. RIDE)?

Comment: Starting with Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to get the current time, run your keyword or keywords, then get the current time again, Then, subtract the starting time from the ending time.

Robot framework provides a [DateTime](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html) module that has functions to support this. For example, [Get current date](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Get%20Current%20Date) can return the current date and time. [Subtract date from date](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html#Get%20Current%20Date) can return a timedelta which can be formatted to days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in your report.

http://robotframework.org/QuickStartGuide/report.html

Elapsed Time:   00:00:00.284

It is also available at Keyword Level in the Test Execution Log.

Comment: I know that,but can we access those elapsed time when test case is running??

Comment: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-start-and-end-time-of-execution I don't know if this will work, but maybe a command line solution is possible...

Comment: Okay Thanks! i will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
${date1} =         Get Current Date
TestCase_To_Rotate_Screen_10_Times
${date2} =         Get Current Date 
${actiontime} =  Subtract Date From Date  ${date2}  ${date1}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Answers with some explanation about why you think it will solve the issue are more helpful.